# Parsing *.chk file and extracting from it the *.docx file

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to parse the *.chk file size of 650 MB and extract from it the *.docx file by looking for the header and trailer in hex (files are opened in streams in binary). This code recieves only first 4 chars and doesn't read on. Please, help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please, enter the file name: ";
    char line[255];
    cin >> line;
    cout << "Please, enter where to put output with filename without . and file format!: ";
    char outp[255];
    int const req=702545920;
    char * thebuff;
    thebuff = new char [req];
    cin >> outp;
    long i=48,j(0);
    ifstream mf;
    mf.open(line, ios::binary);
    char t[7]={};
    char trailer[4]={};
    int64_t start(0),endd(0);
    mf.get(thebuff,req); //doesn't work as I need!_gets only first 4 chars instead of the whole file;
    while (j<=req) // here it gets because of the reason above into an endless loop;
    {
        long temp=j;
        if ((thebuff[j]==(char)0x50) && (thebuff[j+1]==(char)0x4B) && (thebuff[j+2]==(char)0x03) && (thebuff[j+3]==(char)0x04) && (thebuff[j+4]==(char)0x14) && (thebuff[j+5]==(char)0x00) && (thebuff[j+6]==(char)0x06) && (thebuff[j+7]==(char)0x00))
        {
            start = j;
            bool tt(false);
            while (temp<=req && !tt)
            {
                for (int k=0;i<=3;i++)
                {
                    trailer[k] = thebuff[temp+k];
                };
                if ((trailer[0]==(char)0x50) && (trailer[1]==(char)0x4B) && (trailer[2]==(char)0x05) && (trailer[3]==(char)0x06))
                {
                    endd = temp + (long)18;
                    tt = true;
                };
            };
            if (tt)
            {
                start -= 8;
                int bufsize = endd-start;
                char * buffer;
                buffer = new char [bufsize];
                buffer = {};
                int ff(1);
                for (int f=start;f<=endd;f++)
                {
                    buffer[ff]=thebuff[f];
                    ff++;
                };
                ofstream of;
                if ((i<58) || (i>58 && i<92) || (i>92 && i<127)) {outp[sizeof(outp)+1] += (char)i; i++;}
                else if (i>=126) {i=48; outp[sizeof(outp)+1] += (char)i + (char)i;}
                else {i+=5;};
                of.open(outp,ios::binary);
                of.write(buffer,bufsize);
                delete [] buffer;
                j=endd;
            };
        };
        j++;
    };
    delete [] thebuff;
}
```

Comment: Since it is binary data you should probably use `read` rather than `get`.  As far as I know `get` will stop at `\n`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: the read function gives the same result.

Comment: Why do you clutter your code with spontaneous variable definitions? Usually you define variables where you need them (preferably initialize them). Some oldschool style guys define all variables at the beginning of a scope, which is ok also. You define one variable, do something unrelated, define yet another variable, do something to the first and so on. How is anyone supposed to dig through your code? And what is your *actual* problem?

Comment: sorry, really oldschool style(. I came to c++ from pascal.

Comment: The problem is to search through the file.chk, locate the sequence1 of characters, then locate sequence2, then copy all the binary code between these sequences to another file. I.e. exctract from this file multiple others in binary mode.

Comment: The mailfunction locates at actually **reading** the binary file _into memory_. It doesn't read the whole file into char array, but only first 4 characters.

Comment: I find it hard to believe the `read` function doesn't work.  I tested your code reading a jpg file and it reads 81 bytes right up to the first `\n` in the file as expected.  Using `read` I can read the whole file.

Comment: hmm... I see. I will try it on lesser file. I guess the problem is in the size. Will respond later this day.

Comment: @ДмитрийАндре There are much more handy languages like Python or C# than C++.  Are you OK with changing implementation language?

Comment: Well, I consider it possible, if these languages provide more comfortable usage and do actually have some tricks to make this task as possibly easy as it seems.

Referring to the read function -- it causes serious crashes in C++DK while building and conflicts with antivirus avast! resulting in antivirus saying that my program is Win32:Evo-gen [susp] (i.e. Potentially Unwanted Programm). Thus I guess I have to change the implementation language together with the IDE. Thank you.

Comment: After switching off the antivirus, the programm compilated in 1 sec. However it got stuck on file  of 544 kB, specially made for the test. And it has already passed 5 minutes with absolutely no result.

Comment: I might be wrong but I suspect the code posted here is not what you compiled and tried to run.  I think the above code will not output anything because (1) you wrote `long temp=j` but `temp` will never be updated.  (2) therefore `trailer[k]` for `0 <= k < 4` are copy of `thebuff[j+k]` for `0 <= k < 4` (3) then `if ((trailer[0]==(char)0x50) && (trailer[1]==(char)0x4B) && (trailer[2]==(char)0x05) && (trailer[3]==(char)0x06))` is equivalent to `if ((thebuff[j]==(char)0x50) && (thebuff[j+1]==(char)0x4B) && (thebuff[j+2]==(char)0x05) && (thebuff[j+3]==(char)0x06))`

Comment: (4) it never holds inside `if (thebuff[j]==(char)0x50) && (thebuff[j+1]==(char)0x4B) && (thebuff[j+2]==(char)0x03) && (thebuff[j+3]==(char)0x04) && ...` (5) therefore `tt` will never be updated (6) that means `if (tt) ...` never run.  I'm afraid I don't have any time left to help your debugging further.

Comment: Thank you very much. With C# it was more easy to improve the program by working with streams and stream controls without getting all the file into the memory as an array. It works fine now. Still it has bugs, but they are ones I already can cope myself. Thank you once more.

Comment: @nodakai, I got the idea and changed this part by using arrays `header[8]` in place of `thebuff[]` and kept `trailer[4]`. However, I adress them now directly as `header[0], header[1]` etc. Plus, I added the Seek function to make sure that the whole file is read byte-by-byte as I have needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I have made after rewriting this program in C#. It works fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Console.Write("Please, enter the file name: ");
                string line;
                line = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Please, enter where to put output with filename without . and file format!: ");
                string outp;
                outp = Console.ReadLine();
                FileStream mf = new FileStream(line,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
                StreamReader rdmf = new StreamReader(mf);
                char[] header = new char[8];
                char[] trailer = new char[4];
                Console.WriteLine("Programm started successfully!..");
                long start_pos = -8, end_pos = 0, file_count=1;
                while (!rdmf.EndOfStream)
                {
                    start_pos += 8;
                    end_pos = start_pos;
                    rdmf.Read(header,0,8);
                    mf.Seek(-7, SeekOrigin.Current);
                    if ((header[0] == (char)0x50) && (header[1] == (char)0x4B) && (header[2] == (char)0x03) && (header[3] == (char)0x04) && (header[4] == (char)0x14) && (header[5] == (char)0x00) && (header[6] == (char)0x06) && (header[7] == (char)0x00))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Acquiring file...");
                        bool tail_found = false;
                        while (!rdmf.EndOfStream && !tail_found)
                        {
                            rdmf.Read(trailer,0,4);
                            mf.Seek(-3, SeekOrigin.Current);
                            end_pos++;
                            if ((trailer[0]==(char)0x50) && (trailer[1]==(char)0x4B) && (trailer[2]==(char)0x05) && (trailer[3]==(char)0x06))
                            {
                                tail_found = true;
                                end_pos += 18;
                            }
                        }
                        if (tail_found)
                        {
                            mf.Seek(start_pos,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            long seek_inter = end_pos-start_pos;
                            char[] temp = new char[seek_inter];
                            rdmf.Read(temp,0,(int)seek_inter);
                            string[] temp2 = new string[2]; 
                            temp2[0] = temp.ToString();
                            File.WriteAllLines("file"+file_count+".docx",temp2);
                            Console.WriteLine("File "+" 'file"+file_count+".docx' created...");
                            mf.Seek(end_pos,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            start_pos=end_pos-8;
                        }
                    }
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Terminating...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            rdmf.Close();
            mf.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```